# Build errors created by PYBIND11_MOUDLE when binding python and cpp using pybind11 in visual studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pybind11

I am trying to bind my CPP function and use it in python code using pybind11. I have created a visual studio project that includes the function (does not have the main function). I cloned pybind11 from git and added it and python38 /include folders to Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories and python38 /libs folder to Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Library Directories. Also, I added the python38.lib file to Linker/input/Additional Dependencies.

I added

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
```

to the top of my code. And the lines

And I get build errors of the form "unresolved external symbol
"LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_PyThread_tss_create"

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(my_kmeans, handle)
{
    handle.doc() = "Kmeans Clustering";
    handle.def("my_kmeans", &kmeans, "kmeans function");
}
```

Can you please help me fix them?

I tried looking for a .lib file in pybind11 folder but I did not find one.